# how to fix so that the model correctly accepts the size of the data

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

how to pass data so that it is recognized by the queue and no error is thrown

code:

```
import torch
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.nn as nn

class CNN_model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim, dropout):
        super(CNN_model, self).__init__()
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        
        self.conv1d = nn.Conv1d(1, 16, 1, stride = 1)
        self.norm = nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features = input_dim)
        
        self.conv1d_0 = nn.Conv1d(16, 32, 5, stride = 1)
        self.norm_0 = nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features = 32)
        
        self.conv1d_1 = nn.Conv1d(32, 64, 5, stride = 1)
        self.norm_1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features = 64)
        
        self.conv1d_2 = nn.Conv1d(64, 128, 5, stride = 1)
        self.norm_2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features = 128)
        
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(512, 64)
        
        self.output = nn.Linear(64, output_dim)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.conv1d(x.view(1, 1, 16))
        out = self.norm(out)
        out = self.dropout(self.relu(out))
        
        out = self.conv1d_0(out)
        out = self.norm_0(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.conv1d_1(out)
        out = self.norm_1(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.conv1d_2(out)
        out = self.norm_2(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)
        out = self.fc1(out)
        out = self.dropout(self.relu(out))
        out = self.output(out)
        return out

loss_list = []
general_loss = 0

for i in range(10):
    for x, y in train_DataLoader:
        
        train = Variable(x.view(x.size(0), 1, 1, 16).unsqueeze(1))
        traget = Variable(y)
    
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        preds = model(train)
        loss = loss_f(preds, target)
        
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        loss_list.append(loss.item())
```

> ----->Expected 3-dimensional input for 3-dimensional weight [16, 1, 1], but got 5-dimensional input of size [3000, 1, 1, 1, 16] instead

if `.unsqueeze(1)` is not set, it gives the same error but with "4-dimensional input of size"... How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the 1D convolutional network the input must be three-dimensional, as: `(batch_size, channel_size, length)`.

Correcting your reshape to the following should do the trick:

```
>>> train = Variable(x.view(x.size(0), 1, 16))
```

---

*Note: `Variable` is deprecated in newer versions of PyTorch*